# Who is able to see deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've deleted a question,but the number of views is still changing. Who can see my deleted question? Aren't they permanently deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions that are deleted are not visible to most users, but there are some users who can see deleted posts, including:

- The original author of the post
- Users with 10,000 or more reputation (see the [help center's privileges list for 10k rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))
- Elected Moderators (like myself)
- StackExchange Employees

This has always been the case.  Deleted questions are not *permanently* deleted, in that deleted posts can still be viewed by those certain groups of users for historical and/or moderation purposes.

They can also be undeleted under certain circumstances, though this is a much more rare occurrence.

Comment: And heck, they can even be undeleted :D

Comment: I think OP with < 10k gets to see it for a limited time (60 days?) from their profile (OP can directly visit the address following the URL always).